# python отправка письма с помощью smtplib

Tags: python, smtplib

Я хочу отправить письмо из одной электронной почты в другую. Запускаю этот код

```
import smtplib

sender = "" # здесь я вписал свои электронные почты и пароль 
recipient = ""
password = ""
subject = "Тестовое письмо из Python"
text = "Hello from Python"

smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
smtp_server.login(sender, password)
message = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject, text)
smtp_server.sendmail(sender, recipient, message)
smtp_server.close()
```

и у меня вылетает ошибка на 10 строчке `smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials g11sm170351lfv.9 - gsmtp')`, хотя пароль я указал правильный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто разрешите доступ приложениям к вашему аккаунту [тут](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4NRYjLmSw5nBgqeGQwypcVS_v7ITLw8P9LuL0TCaFLquy9G1sWh_AmYtpDw3tEsd3eNPyyN1GACgMK9a0EWZglY9E5_EQ)
Вероятнее всего вам должно помочь,
и разрешите это с того аккаунта с которого скрипт и отправляет письмо
Даже есть статья про этот случай, [тут](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/128490/)